# Complex Mongo DB query - Sub documents

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the document structured as shown [image: here]

I would like to get a collection of moduleDataItems which has version say more than 0.

This is my attempt :

```
            Query qu = Query.query(Criteria.where("appKey")
                    .is("MOCK_APP").and("modules._id")
                    .is("APP_1_MOD_1")
                    .and("modules.moduleDataItems.version")
                    .gt(0));

            List<DataItem> dList = mongoTemplate.find(qu,
                    DataItem.class,
                    ApplicationConstants.MONGO_APPLICATION_COLLECTION_NAME);
```

I m pretty sure I'm not doing the right thing. I do not get any DataItem in the result.

The classes represent the json structure.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally solved it using this -

```
    DBObject unwindParam = new BasicDBObject("$unwind","$dataItems");
    DBObject matchParam = new BasicDBObject("$match",
                                         new BasicDBObject("dataItems.version",
            new BasicDBObject("$gt",requestedModule.getVersion())));                                       
    DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("dataItems", 1);
    DBObject projectParam = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);
    AggregationOutput output = mongoTemplate.getCollection(
                                    "appModules").aggregate(
                                     unwindParam, matchParam,projectParam);
    CommandResult updatedData = output.getCommandResult();
    BasicDBList resList = (BasicDBList) updatedData.get("result");
```